Excel Formula According to the attached table, the rank has been found according to Achieved %, in which some salesman does not have target

According to the attached table, the rank has been found according to Achieved %, in which some salesman does not have target.
The data in this table should come in a new table according to rank order eg:- 1 ,2 ,3 etc .....
.Without target Salesman's Data Should Came Last Rank Data. Below Line Wise .Need formula to arrange Rank Wise Sales Man Data In NEW Table

You could try using the following formula:


=LET(
     _Data, VSTACK(A1:E1,SORTBY(A2:E15,E2:E15)),
     IF(_Data=0,"",_Data))


And if you want to exclude the one which don't have a rank then do the following:
=VSTACK(A1:E1,SORT(FILTER(A2:E15,E2:E15<>""),5))


